# Why isn't there a comma before 'all' in 'Cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C. all owe a debt'?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> Cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C. all owe a debt to
>   Haussmann.

This line is from a passage in Khan Academy SAT Practice. Why don't we need any punctuation between 'D.C.' and 'all'?

Comment: I think the sentence would be clearer by removing the comma between **Washington** and **D.C.** because although there would usually be one, it confuses the list of  *three* locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with adding such a comma is that it would be a single comma separating the subject from the verb. In your sentence, this point is made unclear by the fact that you already have two commas that mark coordination. For this reason, in my explanation, I will be using a sentence that is similar to yours but that doesn't have that complication (see below).

While inserting a single comma between the subject and the verb used to be a common thing to do in previous centuries, nowadays it is (almost) never acceptable.

Normally, in order to be able to put a comma like you suggest, you would also need to add a *they* before *all*:

*Cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C., **they** all owe a debt to Haussmann.*

Here the subject is *they all*, and *cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C.* is a **supplement**.

The only hope for adding that comma to your sentence without adding the *they* is to come up with a special context where *cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C.* would be also be interpreted as a supplement, while the subject is just *all* by itself. I have tried to do this, but haven't been able to. In all cases, my ear still interpreted *cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C.* as the subject, and the result ended up sounding like a sentence where I inserted a comma between the subject and the verb.

(Actually, I did this exercise with a slightly simplified version of the sentence, as discussed below, but the conclusion stands.)

**Discussion**

In what follows I'll be omitting *to Haussmann* as it is not relevant to your question.

The structure of your sentence

[1] *Cities like Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C. all owe a debt.*

is very similar to the structure of the following sentence:

[2] *Cities like those all owe a debt.*

The difference is in the complement of the preposition *like*. In [2], it is *those*, while in [1] it is

[3]  *Chicago, Denver, and Washington, D.C.*

[3] is a coordination of noun phrases (NPs), and so it is functionally like an NP. Since in this case *those* is a counterpart of [3], we would expect that *those,* when used like it is used in [2], should probably functionally be like an NP as well. This is indeed the case. In fact, [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468)  (also called CamGEL) says that when *those* is used as it is used in [2], then it **is** an NP, a so-called  **fused determiner-head NP**.

Let's look at the grammatical structure of [2] in more detail. The subject of [2] is the NP *cities like those*. The universal determinative *all* is not a constituent of this NP, and so it is not part of the subject. This is evident from the cases where the verb phrase requires an auxiliary verb, in which case *all* preferentially comes after the auxiliary:

[4] *Cities like those **have all** owed a debt.*

This is why CGEL says that in sentences like [2] and [4], *all*  is 'a quantificational adjunct functioning in clause structure' (p. 428). It's 'clause structure' rather than 'NP structure'; the latter would be the case if *all* were a part of *cities like those*.

It is clear that no comma is **necessary** anywhere in either [2] or [4]. Moreover, normally it is not possible at all to put a comma between *those* and *all* in [2]:

[5] **Cities like those, all owe a debt.*

If [5] were acceptable, the subject would be *all*, which would now be fused-determiner NP. Meanwhile, *cities like those* would become a **supplement**.

The problem is that [5] doesn't sound like that. To my ear, at least, *cities like those* is still the subject, and we have simply inserted a comma between the subject and the verb.

While putting a comma between the subject and the verb used to be common in previous centuries, nowadays it is almost never acceptable; see [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-with-subjects-and-verbs/) and [here](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/adding-a-comma-between-the-subject-and-predicate-is-inadvisable/). A rare exception is with repeated words, as in *What happened, happened too quickly*. In addition, one should not confuse putting a single comma with inserting a **pair** of delimiting commas that enclose a supplement, as in

[6] *Cities like those, **which have blossomed over the last century,** all owe a debt.*

This is fine; we can insert a supplement between the subject and the verb, and we may use a pair of commas to delimit it. But we can also use em-dashes or parentheses:

[6'] a.  *Cities like those—which have blossomed over the last century—all owe a debt.*
       b.  *Cities like those (which have blossomed over the last century) all owe a debt.*

[5] can be fixed by adding a *they*:

[7] *Cities like those, **they** all owe a debt.*

where the subject is now the compound pronoun *they all* (CGEL, p. 427).

Having said all that, consider the final clause in this passage, which is certainly perfectly fine ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=3-ZMNssUxDAC&lpg=PA86&dq=%22All%20are%20fabulous%20and%20all%20owe%20a%20debt%20to%20the%20spirit%20of%20the%20parrillada%22&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q=%22All%20are%20fabulous%20and%20all%20owe%20a%20debt%20to%20the%20spirit%20of%20the%20parrillada%22&f=false), boldfaced emphasis mine):

> Some of the recipes in this chapter are re-creations of memorable dishes culled from that family trip to Argentina, a few are time-tested family favorites, and one or two are my take on the barbecue/*asado* theme. All are fabulous and **all owe a debt to the spirit of the *parrillada*.**

This passage suggests that [5] might become acceptable if we provide an appropriate context for it. I have thought about it for a bit, and have not been able to come up with one. Certainly it is fine to have a sentence which just says *All owe a debt*. However, in all my attempts, appending *cities like those* (or anything similar) has just been too intrusive: to my ear, the result has always been a sentence where *cities like those* is the subject, and the comma after it is an unwelcome intruder separating the subject from the verb.

Now let's get back to your actual sentence, [1]. The point is that everything I said about the structure of [2] applies equally to [1]. The commas in [3] are markers of **coordination** (together with the *and*). But since there should be no commas in [2], there should likewise be no **extra** commas (beyond those marking coordination) when *those* in [2] is replaced by [3]. The prohibition on placing a single comma between the subject and the verb is just too strong.